# Show the primary key of a table using SQL+ in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, primary-key

i am stuck. i don't know what is the query of SQL+ (Oracle) that allows me to show the primary key of a specific table of a database (by the way i know the name of table after using "select table_name from user_tables;)
in MYSQL we use " SHOW KEYS FROM table WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY' "
but i don't know how to do it using SQL+ (Oracle)
Thank you very much for you attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the prymary key of a specific table with the following query:

```
SELECT constraint_name
FROM user_constraints
WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
AND constraint_type = 'P'
```

Comment: create table JOUE  (
   NOM_ACTEUR VARCHAR2(30) not null,
   TITRE VARCHAR2(40) not null,
   constraint PK_JOUE primary key (NOM_ACTEUR, TITRE),
   constraint FK_JOUE_JOUER_FILM foreign key (TITRE)
         references FILM (TITRE)
);
SELECT constraint_name
FROM user_constraints
WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
AND constraint_type = 'P'